# Prove that $e^x\geq x^{a}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, exponential-function

Prove that $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}:((\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}:e^x\geq x^{a})\iff a\leq e$).

I have looked up numerous theorems and MSE posts and strangely, didn't find anything similar or anything that could help me with this.

Comment: $e^{1/2}\ge(1/2)^4$ even though $4\gt e$.

Comment: @Barry Sorry, I forgot the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part take log and plug $x=e$(as it is given for all $x$ in positive reals.)
Next use the fact $x^{\frac{1}{x}}\leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ if $x$ is positive real. Then $e^{\frac{1}{e}}\leq e^{\frac{1}{a}}$ by the provided inequality on lhs part we are done, thus $x^a\leq e^x$